# Start a function when input-field value changes - JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have two `input` fields. One has a type of hidden (I have done it to an text-type for now) and gets it's value dynamically. Depended on this value, I will show an `alert` with that value and show some specific information after the other `input` field.

Let's say the `input` field has first a value of table_rate:38 (the value could also be empty). And now the problem starts. When the value of the `input` field changes to table_rate:23, then an `alert` should come up and information should be shown after the other `input` field. But it does not work.

Here can you the HTML:

```
<p class="form-row form-row form-row-wide address-field validate-required validate-postcode form-row-first woocommerce-validated" id="billing_postcode_field" data-o_class="form-row form-row form-row-wide address-field validate-required validate-postcode">
    <label for="billing_postcode" class="">
        Postnummer 
        <abbr class="required" title="påkrevet">*</abbr>
    </label>
    <input type="text" class="input-text " name="billing_postcode" id="billing_postcode" placeholder="Postnummer" value="" autocomplete="off">
</p>

<input type="text" name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_method_0" value="table_rate:38" class="shipping_method">
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/9fzc3ozu/1/) you can see the full JSFiddle.

How can I fix this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The problem is in the if statement, try it like this: if (zone == 'table_rate:33') with double equal signs and it will work

Comment: Thanks for your comment but this did not work, I am afraid.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly `trigger` the change in your `setInterval` method.

```
setInterval(function(){
    $('#shipping_method_0').val('table_rate:23');
    $('#shipping_method_0').trigger("change");  // after updating the input, trigger 'change' event
}, 1000);
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dLo472bs/12/)

Answer (score 0):

Hey try this Jquery hope it helps you

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){       
$('.shipping_method').on('change', function() {
alert( "your value changed To  "   +  this.value );
})
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find below the changed fiddle, just as I have mentioned

```
if (zone == 'table_rate:38') {
    $("#billing_postcode").after("<span id='contenttoshow'>Varene vil bli levert til:<br>" +
        "Sped trans, " +
        "Titangaten 11, " +
        "1630 Gamle Fredrikstad<br></span>");
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dLo472bs/13/